# UInt8 from objective c analog in unmanaged c++

Tags: c++

What is analog of UInt8 in unmanaged c++ and what #include it requies?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about but I'd guess it's `uint8_t` and `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: you can use uint8* in your code. But why do you need a uint8 for your code ? It would be better if you can state clearly what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you for the ansvers. Krammer, what include I need to use uint8*

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t var;
```